# MultipleObjectsReturned at /review/2 get() returned more than one Project -- it returned 2

Tags: django

I have an application where users can register and create a profile. After they create their profile, they are able to store their data. The most important part in this data is that users fill in the quantity and the price among others, and the total is calculated by a simple function. I also have another model with a function too, which calculates the users current margin by adding their total sales and subtracting this from the total from the previous model and storing it in a field name margin in the second table. It works well when a user creates their first instance, and the next margin function is called. If the same user creates another instance, that works too, but i get this error "MultipleObjectsReturned at /review/2, get() returned more than one Project -- it returned 2!" while calculating the margin. I would like the logged in user to save multiple objects or data, if they have too. I have looked for a relatable solution for days but none has helped me. Please show me a way.

This is the model which makes the app through this exception:

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    juror = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, Profile, related_name='reviews', null=True)
    margin = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)
    sales = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.margin = self.sales - Project.objects.get_or_create(posted_by=self.juror).total
        if self.sales > self.margin:

            self.margin =  self.margin
        else:
            -self.margin
        return super().save( *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def get_reviews(cls):
        reviews = Reviews.objects.all()
        return reviews
```

This is how my view looks like:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def add_review(request,pk):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    current_user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sales = form.cleaned_data['sales']
            margin = form.cleaned_data['margin']
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.project = project
            review.juror = current_user
            review.sales = sales
            review.margin = margin
            review.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()
        return render(request,'review.html',{"user":current_user,"form":form})
```

Comment: It means that `Project.objects.get_or_create(posted_by=self.juror)` returned *two* items, so a `Project` has two records where `posted_by` is `self.juror`.

Comment: @WilliamOnSem, I agree with you . Yes I would like to have multiple projects by the same user. How can I query different Projects, such that as I calculate the margin, I calculate it for each specific project ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of;

```
self.margin = self.sales - Project.objects.get_or_create(posted_by=self.juror).total
```

I changed this line of code to read ;

```
self.margin = self.sales - Project.objects.last().total
```

This way, for every new entry to get the subtracted(margin) value, it calls the last posted data. This solution works. But i've proven if I subtract from a former project entry, it deducts from the last entry value. However, its a good halfway solution if those prior projects have their margin values already recorded.